# difficulties evaluating if a ordinal multnomial model fitted with polr (in Rstudio) can be used for predicting over new data

Tags: r, ordinal-data, multinomial-distribution, polr

I'm getting very different output when i perform a multinomial ordinal model depending on wether I scale or not my data first. Anyone could tell me why?

Here are the results with raw data:

```
 polr(formula = result ~ 1 + Speed + rsvl + rsvl:Speed + tailcontrst:Reltailsize + 
 strategy:rsvl, data = results)

Coefficients:
                         Value Std. Error t value
Speed                   -0.1758606  0.0149032 -11.800
rsvl                     7.9648646  0.0345985 230.209
Speed:rsvl              -0.3342932  0.0259837 -12.865
tailcontrst:Reltailsize  0.0004315  0.0001678   2.572
rsvl:strategyburrowing  -0.8982385  0.0746702 -12.029

Intercepts:
            Value    Std. Error t value 
fail|tail  -0.1186   0.0689    -1.7216
tail|body   0.4728   0.0669     7.0701

Residual Deviance: 20457.78 
AIC: 20471.78
```

Here are the results with scaled data:

```
polr(formula = result ~ 1 + Speed + rsvl + rsvl:Speed + tailcontrst:Reltailsize + 
strategy:rsvl, data = results)

Coefficients:
                            Value Std. Error  t value
Speed                   -0.97646    0.02083 -46.8841
rsvl                     0.30276    0.02726  11.1064
Speed:rsvl              -0.06810    0.02097  -3.2467
tailcontrst:Reltailsize  0.01092    0.01895   0.5760
rsvl:strategyburrowing  -0.02332    0.03841  -0.6069

Intercepts:
            Value    Std. Error t value 
fail|tail  -0.5332   0.0208   -25.6952
tail|body   0.0516   0.0202     2.5480

Residual Deviance: 20608.95 
AIC: 20622.95
```

The best AIC is given by the non transformed data so I would rather use them, if none here tells me the contrary.

The model is suposed to be the best combination of factors among all the possible combinations. I obtained it using the function GLmulti. However, despite the t values are quite big and the graphs make sense with the existence of significant effects, the chi-squared test tells me the fit is very bad (value=0). Someone could tell me how do I evaluate if i can rely on this model to make predictions based on new data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `polr` from the package `MASS`? Nothing in your question seems to require Rstudio as such.

Comment: yes, polr from the package MASS. I just wanted to inform I executed the model using Rstudio.

Comment: I don't see the commands you used to scale the data. Perhaps there is an error there. If you plot each scaled variable versus its corresponding raw variable, you should get nothing but straight lines. ... Oh, and if you scaled 'result' too, it's no wonder, because you're no long modeling the sMe response variable. Either way, we need more details on what you mean by scaling.

Comment: sorry, here is the only command used:   results[,c("Speed","rsvl","Reltailsize","tailcontrst")]=colwise(scale)(results[,c("Speed","rsvl","Reltailsize","tailcontrst")]). plotting the raw and scaled variables gives the line you told me.